# breaking out from a for loop with a strstr NULL return

Tags: c, strstr

What am I not getting here?

This works pretty well:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 5 && found != 0 ;++i ){ no difference than above
        found=strcmp( name, myContacts[i].cFirstName);
        printf(" i %d\n", i);
    }
printf(" \nName Found %s",  myContacts[i-1].cFirstName );
```

But just out of curiosity, I'm trying to use also strstr().

```
/*** This achieves the same functionality as above ***/

    for ( i = 0; i < 5  ;i++ ){
    found2=strstr( myContacts[i].cFirstName , name);
    printf(" i %d\n", i);
    if (found2 != NULL)
        {
        printf(" \nName Found %s",  myContacts[i].cFirstName );
        break;
        }
    }
```

This however is not working:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 5 && found2 != '\0' ;i++ ){ //this does not work as above
for ( i = 0; i < 5 && found2 != NULL ;i++ ){ // this also is not wroking
        found2=strstr( myContacts[i].cFirstName , name);
}

printf(" \nName Found %s",  myContacts[i].cFirstName );
```

Thanks in advance for you suggestions.

Full code:

```
# please take my codes with a grain of skepticism, I am still learning 
# i know of sizeof(), but I rather not use it just for the purpose of my exercise

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXBUFFERSIZE   10

typedef struct contact {

    char cFirstName[10];
    char cLastName[10];
    char cTelphone[12];

} address ; // end type

// function prototype
void printContacts( address * );
void printMenu();
char getChoice();
void storeContact( address [] ,  int *);
//int searchContact( address [] , char * );
void searchContact( address [] , char [] );

int main(){

    char cSelection = 0;
    address myContacts[5];
    char buffer[MAXBUFFERSIZE];

    int i ;
    // initialize array to be zeros
    for ( i = 0; i < 5 ; i++ ){
        strcpy(myContacts[i].cFirstName, "0");
        strcpy(myContacts[i].cLastName,"0");
        strcpy(myContacts[i].cTelphone,"0"); 
    }

    strcpy(myContacts[0].cFirstName, "Jonny");
    strcpy(myContacts[1].cFirstName, "Julia");
    strcpy(myContacts[2].cFirstName, "Claudia");
    strcpy(myContacts[3].cFirstName, "Aaron");
    strcpy(myContacts[4].cFirstName, "Sebastian");

    int iDel = -1 ; // store the position if one deleted
    int iCount = 0 ; // counter for position in the array, when 
                     // inserting names.

    while ( cSelection != '5' ) {
    printMenu();
    cSelection = getChoice();

    switch (cSelection) {
        case '1':
            printContacts( myContacts );    
            break;

        case '2':
            if ( ( iDel >= -1 ) && ( iCount < 5 ) ){
                //printf("\niCount is %d ", iCount);
                storeContact( myContacts, &iCount );
                iCount++;
                //printf("\nOutside storeContact, *Plocation %d", iCount );
                }
            if ( iCount >= 5 ) {
                printf("\nThe Memory is full, consider deleting some"\
                "Contacts");    
                }
            break;

        case '3':
            {            
            printf("\nEnter a name or part of a name to search:\n");
            fscanf(stdin, "%s", buffer);
            getchar(); // clear the last enter
            printf("\nThe line you entered was:\n");
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
            searchContact( myContacts, buffer );
            break;
            }       
        case '4':   
            //iDel=deleteContact( myContacts );
            break;

        }// end of switch
    }// end of while
    return 0;
} // end main

char getChoice(){

    char cSelection = 'q'; //for the menu
    /**** always scanf CHARS so you can check
     *    if digit or char !!! ****/

    scanf("%s", &cSelection);

    while ( strlen(&cSelection) != 1 ){
        printf("\nChoich not understood, enter a number again:");
        scanf("%s",&cSelection);
        }

    if ( isalpha(cSelection) ){
        printf( "You entered a letter of the alphabet\n" );
        cSelection = -1;
        printf( "Illegal choice !!!" );
      }

    return cSelection;
    } 

void printContacts( address * myContacts ){

    int i ;

    for ( i = 0; strcmp(myContacts[i].cFirstName,"0") != 0 && i < 5 ; i++ ){                                             
        printf("\nmyContacts[%d].cFirstName: %s", i, \
        myContacts[i].cFirstName );
    }// end for
}

void printMenu(){
    printf("\n\n\tSilly Phone Book\n\n");
    printf("\n\n1\tPrint Phone Book\n");
    printf("2\tAdd New Contact\n");
    printf("3\tSearch For Contact\n");
    printf("4\tDelete Contact\n");
    printf("5\tQuit\n");
    printf("\nSelect Action: ");
    }

//void storeContact( address myContacts[] ){ //syntactic sugar
void storeContact( address * myContacts,  int *Plocation ){ 

    char ch;                     /* handles user input */
    char buffer[MAXBUFFERSIZE];  /* sufficient to handle one line */
    int x = 0;
    x=*Plocation;

    ch = getchar(); // clear the last enter
    printf("Enter a name (<10 characters)\n");
    //ch = getchar();
    //char_count = 0;
    //while( (ch != '\n')  && (ch != EOF ) &&  (char_count < MAXBUFFERSIZE)) {
        //buffer[char_count++] = ch;
        //ch = getchar();
    //}
    //buffer[char_count] = 0x00;      /* null terminate buffer */

    //fgets(buffer,11,stdin);

    fscanf(stdin, "%s", buffer); /* read from keyboard */

    printf("\nThe line you entered was:\n");
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    //TODO: add check that string is not too long!!!
    // if we do that, the code won't blow here ?

    strcpy(myContacts[x].cFirstName, buffer);    
} 

//int searchContact( address * myContacts,    char name[] ){
void searchContact( address * myContacts,    char * name ){
    int found;
    char *found2;
    //printf("\nHey dude im buffer from inside searchContact: %s", name);
    // iterate throught the array, print possible matches
    int i = 0;


    //for ( i = 0; i < 5 && found != 0 ;i++ ){
    //for ( i = 0; i < 5 && found != 0 ;++i ){ no difference than above
        //found=strcmp( name, myContacts[i].cFirstName);
        //printf(" i %d\n", i);
    //}
    //printf(" \nName Found %s",  myContacts[i-1].cFirstName );

    /*** This achieves the same functionality as above 

    for ( i = 0; i < 5  ;i++ ){
    found2=strstr( myContacts[i].cFirstName , name);
    printf(" i %d\n", i);
    if (found2 != NULL)
        {
        printf(" \nName Found %s",  myContacts[i].cFirstName );
        break;
        }
    }    ***/

    for ( i = 0; i < 5 && &found2 != '\0' ;i++ ){ //this does not work as above
        found2=strstr( myContacts[i].cFirstName , name);
        printf("found %p i %d\n", found2, i);
        //printf(" \nName Found %s",  myContacts[i].cFirstName );
    }

    //return found;
} // end of searchContacts  if ( isalpha(cSelection) ){
        printf( "You entered a letter of the alphabet\n" );
        cSelection = -1;
        printf( "Illegal choice !!!" );
      }

    return cSelection;
    } 

void printContacts( address * myContacts ){

    int i ;

    for ( i = 0; strcmp(myContacts[i].cFirstName,"0") != 0 && i < 5 ; i++ ){                                             
        printf("\nmyContacts[%d].cFirstName: %s", i, \
        myContacts[i].cFirstName );
    }// end for
}

void printMenu(){
    printf("\n\n\tSilly Phone Book\n\n");
    printf("\n\n1\tPrint Phone Book\n");
    printf("2\tAdd New Contact\n");
    printf("3\tSearch For Contact\n");
    printf("4\tDelete Contact\n");
    printf("5\tQuit\n");
    printf("\nSelect Action: ");
    }

//void storeContact( address myContacts[] ){ //syntactic sugar
void storeContact( address * myContacts,  int *Plocation ){ 

    char ch;                     /* handles user input */
    char buffer[MAXBUFFERSIZE];  /* sufficient to handle one line */
    int x = 0;
    x=*Plocation;

    ch = getchar(); // clear the last enter
    printf("Enter a name (<10 characters)\n");
    //ch = getchar();
    //char_count = 0;
    //while( (ch != '\n')  && (ch != EOF ) &&  (char_count < MAXBUFFERSIZE)) {
        //buffer[char_count++] = ch;
        //ch = getchar();
    //}
    //buffer[char_count] = 0x00;      /* null terminate buffer */

    //fgets(buffer,11,stdin);

    fscanf(stdin, "%s", buffer); /* read from keyboard */

    printf("\nThe line you entered was:\n");
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    //TODO: add check that string is not too long!!!
    // if we do that, the code won't blow here ?

    strcpy(myContacts[x].cFirstName, buffer);    
} 

//int searchContact( address * myContacts,    char name[] ){
void searchContact( address * myContacts,    char * name ){
    int found;
    char *found2;
    //printf("\nHey dude im buffer from inside searchContact: %s", name);
    // iterate throught the array, print possible matches
    int i = 0;


    //for ( i = 0; i < 5 && found != 0 ;i++ ){
    //for ( i = 0; i < 5 && found != 0 ;++i ){ no difference than above
        //found=strcmp( name, myContacts[i].cFirstName);
        //printf(" i %d\n", i);
    //}
    //printf(" \nName Found %s",  myContacts[i-1].cFirstName );

    /*** This achieves the same functionality as above 

    for ( i = 0; i < 5  ;i++ ){
    found2=strstr( myContacts[i].cFirstName , name);
    printf(" i %d\n", i);
    if (found2 != NULL)
        {
        printf(" \nName Found %s",  myContacts[i].cFirstName );
        break;
        }
    }    ***/

    for ( i = 0; i < 5 && found2 != '\0' ;i++ ){ //this does not work as above
        found2=strstr( myContacts[i].cFirstName , name);
        printf("found %p i %d\n", found2, i);
        //printf(" \nName Found %s",  myContacts[i].cFirstName );
    }

    //return found;
} // end of searchContacts
```

Just for the completeness of this discussion, I'm adding what finally really worked as I wanted it. 
This came after going through all the answers, so thanks everyone:

I forgot to initialize the pointer:

```
char *found2=NULL;
```

Now the following loop works as expected:

```
 for ( i = 0; i < 5 && !found2 ;i++ ){ //this does work as above

        found2=strstr( myContacts[i].cFirstName , name);
        printf("i %d\n", i);

    }
    printf("Name found %s", found2);
```

I wanted this functionallity with strstr() because now I can search "Clau" and match it to "Claudia".
This is better for my needs than strcmp(), although I am quite sure it can be done also with strcmp(), with more sophistication or better skills in C than I have.

Thanks again for the answers!

Comment: I see several things here that are, perhaps, wrong.  But none of them is _definitely_ your problem.  Please post a complete, self-contained program that can be compiled and run and will show us what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `found2` is a `char *`.

You should write `for (i = 0; i < 5 && !found2; i++) //etc etc`

(or test for `found2` in the loop and break if non NULL)

Comment: that is exactly what i did and is working. I just dont get why my other solution which compiles does not do what i want to do.

Comment: Because you try to see if `&found2`, which is the address of `found2`, not a char, is not 0... Which will pretty much be always true. But what `found2` will point to will be completely arbitrary

Answer (score 1):

don't use cicles.
By using strstr() you just need to use it once so:

```
found2=strstr( myContacts[i].cFirstName , name);
printf(" \nName Found %s",  found2 );
```

(don't forget the corresponding check for null)

Answer (score 1):

With your condition in the `for` loop:

```
&found2 != '\0'
```

You're wanting to check if `found2` is pointing to `NULL`, as you even mention yourself, so make that `found2 != NULL`. Otherwise you're comparing the **address** of `found2` to the NUL character (`'\0'`), which is definitely not what you're wanting to do.

However, you're also wrong in saying that the `strstr` snippet has the same functionality as the `strcmp` snippet; the two functions are completely different. [Read the documentation for `strstr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strstr.html).

Another thing, in your first snippet `"Name Found"` is always going to be printed

There's also so many more wrong things with your code, such as:

```
scanf("%s", &cSelection);
...
while ( strlen(&cSelection)
```

`cSelection` is declared as a `char`, if you want to store a `char` in it use the format specifier `%c`. If you want to read in a whole string, make it a `char` **array**, and the `&` is unnecessary when passing the address of an array to a function.

Same foes for `&cSelection` being passed to `strlen`. Makes no sense for the same reasons.

`(f)scanf` is also unsafe for reading strings and can cause buffer overflows, you should use `fgets(STRING, SIZE, stdin)` instead. Anyway just turn up your compiler warnings so you can catch all of the above.

Comment: I was using fgets() you can see it is commented there. Somehow, I had problems with it, but I don't remember what.

Comment: Regarding compiler warning, I compile with gcc -Wall, and I didn't see any warning about it. Any more flags I should use ?

Comment: @Oz123 `-pedantic` is another one, however are you sure you weren't getting any warnings?

Comment: thanks, I like the -pedantic flag. But I still get only 2 additional warnings: PhoneBook3e.c:14:13: warning: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
PhoneBook3e.c:44: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code